# Java How to read/write a file in classpath from a static method

Tags: java, file-writing

I am making license for my employer's software products. The application is a web application deployed in tomcat. The application is deployed at cusotmer premise.

I am using maven as build tool. My testing license file is located at `src/main/resources/License.lic`. That means I need to read License.lic which has encrypted text. After user login, I decrypt and checking license is still valid or not. Finally I write something back into license file (License.lic).

The problem I met is that after checking, I modify updated text and encrypt it, but fail to write back to license.lic. The read and write both are in static method.

My codes for writing back to License.lic is as follows:

```
protected static void writeToLicense(LicenseData licData) throws Exception{
        String plainText = licData.toString();
        String encText = LicenseEncDec.encrypt(plainText);
        System.out.println("encText is "+encText);

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URL url = classLoader.getResource(licFileName1);
        File file = new File(url.toURI().getPath());    

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        pw.println(encText);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
```

Reading from License.lic is as follows:

```
private static String readFile() throws IOException {

    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream(licFileName1);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

    String line = br.readLine();

    br.close();
    is.close();

    return line;
}
```

The License.lic could not be written back to. Anything wrong with my codes?

Comment: You are assuming the License.lic is a writable file on your file system. If it is not, you need to consider how it is stored. e.g. is it in a JAR?

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: @NielsNet I am giess it attempts to write to a local file, but reads from the class path. So I wouldn't expect any errors, just the file doesn't change.

Comment: why would you want to put time in this? if your client wants to use your code without paying a "license", all he has to do is decompile your code, remove the check, and -- presto. If you want some (better) security, only provide a client to your client, and have your business logic run on a server the client can't manipulate

Comment: I read from License.lic and it is writable. License.lic is in classpath. So I could both read and write. And there is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

That is a wrong design. A decently secured web application should never have permissions to write into its own code nor anywhere in classpath. Full stop. Not doing that offers illimited attack vectors if one single piece of the application was to be compromised.

So anything under `src/main/resources` should be seen as read only. The correct way would be to have a dedicated directory, optionally declared in an environment variable where you can write whatever you need. If it not an accident if `getResource` only gives readonly access, and any attempt to circumvent it will bring problems:

- security as I explained in my first paragraph
- unexploded wars are by definition read only

Once you have a *data* directory somewhere, no mode headache for converting a resource to a plain file: you have a plain file and can do what you want with it.

I must acknowledge that this is little more than my opinion, but I really urge you to think twice about writable resources.